# Регулярные выражения питон вытянуть количество

Tags: python, html, регулярные-выражения

Есть предложения, не могу сформировать регулярное выражение. Нужно вытянуть цифры (в данном случаем "2"):

1)

```
<div class="header_top clear_fix">
                <span class="header_label fl_l">Друзья</span>
                <span class="header_count fl_l">2</span>
              </div>
```

2. 

Вытянуть что количество фотографии "1"

```
onclick="return showAlbums(555861, {noHistory: true}, event);">
  <div class="count">1</div>
  <div class="label">фотография</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Может, лучше воспользоваться специализированными средствами для разбора HTML, а не регулярками? К тому же, Вы не привели своих попыток.

Answer (score 3):

думаю здесь лучше использовать модуль [BeautifulSoup](https://python-scripts.com/beautifulsoup-html-parsing)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = """
<div class="header_top clear_fix">
                <span class="header_label fl_l">Друзья</span>
                <span class="header_count fl_l">2</span>
              </div>

onclick="return showAlbums(555861, {noHistory: true}, event);">
  <div class="count">1</div>
  <div class="label">фотография</div>
</a>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
print(soup.find("span", class_ = "header_count").text)
print(soup.find("div", class_ = "count").text)
```

вывод:

> ```
> 2
> 1
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Если вы на вход получаете строки "Друзья 2" и "1 фотография", то достаточно будет `r'(\d)'`

Comment: отдельно переменную количество друзья b=2 и количество фотографии k=1

Comment: digit = re.compile('(\d)')

b = digit.findall(строка_друзей)[0]
k = digit.findall(строка_фото)[0]